# permission denied for mpicc

Tags: permissions, mpi

I am trying to install and

```
make[1]: /usr/bin/mpicc: Permission denied
make[1]: *** [molmatch.o] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I have mpicc installed in `/usr/bin/mpicc`

and checked the paths in make files in src and lib

I have tried `sudo make`

Any ideas why permission is denied?

Comment: what happens if you su to root and attempt to make a directory in /usr/bin?

Comment: You could also install MPI in some other location like `/usr/local/` instead of `/usr`, or your home directory.